# How to overcome infinite value to perform multicollinearity test in environmental variables?

Tags: geospatial, data-analysis, spatial, multicollinearity, spatial-data

### Here's the dataset which consists of X = 45 columns collected the data from bioclimate database.
The multicollinearity test model -

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
vif_data = pd.DataFrame()
vif_data["feature"] = X.columns
```

---

### [x columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2cj4.png)

```
#Calculating VIF for each feature
vif_data["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i)
              for i in range (0, len(X.columns))]
-------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/stats/outliers_influence.py:193: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
vif = 1. / (1. - r_squared_i)
```

### [vif_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxE5H.png)

**Trial :**

- I've converted all variables into float and int vice-versa but still getting infinite values for all variables after performing multicollinearity test.
- I didn't find any reference material to tackle this problem specially in python.
  Please help me out, I am using it for species distribution modelling.

Comment: vif is inf if variables are perfectly collinear, that is if the r-squared of the regression of one explanatory variable on all other explanatory variables is 1. Do you have fewer observations than columns?

Comment: Also, note that statsmodels variance inflation factor assumes a constant or demeaned variables as in the design matrix of a regression model

Comment: Yes, the column size 48 and rows 28 and all are based on presence location.